# Invoke Error updating Business Central to v20

Tags: dynamics-business-central

Trying to update to BC20 and I am getting an error at the Invoke-NAVApplicationDatabaseConversion command saying:

Invoke-NAVApplicationDatabaseConversion : A technical upgrade of database 'Demo Database BC (19-0)' on server
'LOCALHOST\BCDEMO' cannot be run, because the database�s application version '131112' is greater than or equal to the
platform version '131112'.

Does anyone know a fix for this or what I need to do?
Here is my whole script:

```
    $OldBcServerInstance = "BC190"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\190\Service\NavAdminTool.ps1"
Restart-NAVServerInstance -ServerInstance $OldBcServerInstance


$OldBcServerInstance = "BC190"
$NewBcServerInstance = "BC200"
$ApplicationDatabase = "Demo Database BC (19-0)" 
$DatabaseServer = "localhost\BCDEMO"
$SystemAppPath = "C:\BBS\cu2\Dynamics.365.BC.38230.US.DVD (1)\Applications\system application\source\Microsoft_System Application.app"
$BaseAppPath = "C:\BBS\cu2\Dynamics.365.BC.38230.US.DVD (1)\Applications\BaseApp\Source\Microsoft_Base Application.app"
$ApplicationAppPath = "C:\BBS\cu2\Dynamics.365.BC.38230.US.DVD (1)\Applications\Application\Source\Microsoft_Application.app"
$NewBCVersion = "20.0.37253.38230"
$PartnerLicense = "C:\BBS\5317559_BC20\5317559.flf"
$CustomerLicense = "The file path and name of the customer license"
$AddinsFolder = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\190\Service\Add-ins\"



Invoke-NAVApplicationDatabaseConversion -DatabaseServer $DatabaseServer -DatabaseName $ApplicationDatabase
Set-NAVServerConfiguration -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -KeyName DatabaseName -KeyValue $ApplicationDatabase
Set-NavServerConfiguration -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -KeyName "EnableTaskScheduler" -KeyValue false
Restart-NAVServerInstance -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance
Import-NAVServerLicense -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -LicenseFile $PartnerLicense
Restart-NAVServerInstance -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance
Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Path $SystemAppPath
Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Path $BaseAppPath
Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Path $ApplicationAppPath
Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Path "C:\projects\LoanVisionLite\Bestborn Business Solutions, LLC_LoanVisionLite_1.0.0.0.app" -SkipVerification
Get-NAVAppInfo -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance | Where-Object {$_.Publisher -notlike 'Microsoft'} | Repair-NAVApp
Restart-NAVServerInstance -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance
Start-NAVAppDataUpgrade -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Name "System Application" -Version $NewBCVersion
Start-NAVAppDataUpgrade -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Name "Base Application" -Version $NewBCVersion
Start-NAVAppDataUpgrade -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -Name "Application" -Version $NewBCVersion

Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.BusinessChart' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'BusinessChart\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.BusinessChart.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.FlowIntegration' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'FlowIntegration\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.FlowIntegration.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.OAuthIntegration' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'OAuthIntegration\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.OAuthIntegration.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.PageReady' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'PageReady\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.PageReady.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.PowerBIManagement' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'PowerBIManagement\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.PowerBIManagement.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.RoleCenterSelector' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'RoleCenterSelector\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.RoleCenterSelector.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.SatisfactionSurvey' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'SatisfactionSurvey\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.SatisfactionSurvey.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.SocialListening' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'SocialListening\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.SocialListening.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.VideoPlayer' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'VideoPlayer\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.VideoPlayer.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WebPageViewer' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'WebPageViewer\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WebPageViewer.zip')
Set-NAVAddIn -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -AddinName 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WelcomeWizard' -PublicKeyToken 31bf3856ad364e35 -ResourceFile ($AppName = Join-Path $AddinsFolder 'WelcomeWizard\Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.WelcomeWizard.zip')

Set-NAVApplication -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -ApplicationVersion $NewBCVersion -Force
Start-NAVDataUpgrade -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -FunctionExecutionMode Serial
Set-NAVServerConfiguration -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance -KeyName SolutionVersionExtension -KeyValue "437dbf0e-84ff-417a-965d-ed2bb9650972" -ApplyTo All
Restart-NAVServerInstance -ServerInstance $NewBcServerInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting the error because you are using the version 19 PowerShell Modules:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\190\Service\NavAdminTool.ps1"
```

In order to do the technical upgrade from one version to another you must use the PowerShell Modules of the new version. Depending on your where you installed the new version it could be e.g.:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\200\Service\NavAdminTool.ps1"
```

Note that the folder `190` has been changed to `200`.